# How do you calculate memory access time?

Tags: c++

I create a large boolean 2d array (5000X5000 for a total of 25 billion elements at 23MB). Then I loop through and instantiate every element with a random true or false. Then I loop through and read every single element. All 25 million elements are read in ~100ms.

23MB is too big to fit in the CPU's cache and I think my program is too simple to benefit from any type of compiler optimization so am I right to conclude that the program is reading 25 million elements from RAM in ~100ms?

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <chrono>
    using namespace std;

    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
        bool **locs;
        locs = new bool*[5000];
        for(int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
            locs[i] = new bool[5000];
        for(int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
            for(int i2 = 0; i2 < 5000; i2++)
                locs[i][i2] = rand() % 2 == 0 ? true : false;
        int *idx = new int [5000*5000];
        for(int i = 0; i < 5000*5000; i++)
            *(idx + i) = rand() % 4999;

        bool val;
        int memAccesses = 0;
        auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        for(int i = 0; i < 5000*5000; i++) {
            val = locs[*(idx + i)][*(idx + ++i)];
            memAccesses += 2;
        }
        auto finish = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

        std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(finish-start).count() << " ns\n";
        std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(finish-start).count() << " ms\n";
        cout << "TOTAL MEMORY ACCESSES: " << memAccesses << endl;
        cout << "The size of the array in memory is " << ((sizeof(bool)*5000*5000)/1048576) << "MB";

        int exit; cin >> exit;
        return 0;
    }

    /*
    OUTPUT IS:

        137013700 ns
        137 ms
        TOTAL MEMORY ACCESSES: 25000000
        The size of the array in memory is 23MB
    */
```

Comment: `5000*5000` is 25 _m_illion, not 25 _b_illion.

Comment: It would be interesting that you actually _do_ something with the boolean value you read ("val"). Otherwise, you risk compiler optimizations kicking in and not actually reading the values. For example, you could count `true` values and print out the count once the loop is finished.

Comment: depending on implementation, bool may not be 1 byte

Comment: @Carsten it's called an extra short billion ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As other answers have mentioned, the "speed" you are seeing (even if the CPU is executing your code and it is not stripped by the compiler) is about 250 MBps, which is very very low number for modern systems.

However, your methodology seems flawed to me (admittedly, I'm not an expert in benchmarking.) And here are the problems I see:

1. For any benchmark such as this, even in the simplest form, you need to distinguish *random-access* from *sequential-access*. Memory is **not** a random-access device (despite its name) and performs very poorly here. Your code seems to be accessing memory randomly, so you add that to your conclusion as a qualifier: that you are "reading 25 million elements *from random locations* from RAM in ~100ms."
2. Another aspect of this sort of benchmarks is the concept of latency vs. throughput. Again, if you want to conclude anything from your numbers and timings, you need to be aware what are you measuring exactly.
3. You are counting memory accesses incorrectly. Depending of the exact code your compiler is generating, this line:

   ```
   val = locs[*(idx + i)][*(idx + ++i)];
   ```

   might realistically access the memory system anywhere between 4 to 9 times.

   - At best, if `i`, `idx`, `locs` and `val` are all either in registers or access to them is eliminated, then you need to read `*(idx + i)`, read `locs[*(idx + i)]` (remember that `locs` is an array of pointers to arrays, *not* a 2D array,) read `*(idx + ++i)`, and finally read `locs[*(idx + i)][*(idx + ++i)]`. A few of these might be cached, but it's unlikely, with the cache-thrashing that's going on.
   - At worst, in addition to the above, you need two accesses for `++i` (read, then write back,) one for `idx`, one for `locs` and one for `val`. I don't know, you might even need another read for the single `i` and/or two reads for the two `idx` occurrences (due to pointer aliasing and whatnot.)
4. You need to be aware that memory is *never* accessed in single bytes or even words. *Memory is always read and written in units of cache-line*. And cache line size can be different from system to system, although the most common size these days is 64 bytes. So, each time you read a memory location that is not in the cache, you are loading 64-bytes (or more) from RAM. If the memory locations you are reading are at the cache line boundary (some of the bytes in one cache line and some in the next) then you are loading two cache lines from RAM. Given a sane compiler and properly aligned variables in memory, this doesn't happen very often, but it might. So you have to at least multiply your calculated bandwidth used by the size of your cache line.
5. However, if you are accessing a memory location that is already in cache, then you don't load anything from RAM. You need to consider this in your conclusions too.
6. You also need to consider cache line eviction, your cache's associativity, number of levels, the fact that some cache levels are shared between instructions and data and some aren't, some are shared between cores and some aren't, and a lot of other things when evaluating the performance of caches and memory.
7. The DRAM chips also have a lot of weird and complex behaviors and characteristics. Some memory locations are faster to read after some others (due to the arrangements of rows and columns,) some accesses might get delayed a long time (at CPU speeds) because of the refresh cycle, other devices might be using the RAM or the bus that RAM is on, etc., etc. I'm far from familiar with the operations of modern memory chips, and even I know that it's a complete mess.
8. You *have* to consider the effects of compiler optimization on your code. This means that you have to look t your code after the compiler is done with it, in assembly form. You need to look at the generated assembly to be able to know what your code is actually doing: whether and which of your memory accesses are optimized out.

All in all, I don't think that you can conclude much useful information from your program. Sorry about that, but memory is very complex!

Answer (score 2):

No.  The reads won't always go all the way down to the RAM.  Blocks of memory get pulled into the cache when a read (or write) is performed.  As long as the block from which you are reading is already in the cache, the cache is used.  If you request data from a block that is not in the cache, then the RAM is accessed to fetch the block of memory and place it in the cache.  Reading from the cache is significantly cheaper than reading from RAM.

**EDIT**
Again, write oprerations cause blocks from memory to get pulled into the cache.  Because you are storing the values in your program before reading them, the data you are reading is most likely already in the cache from when you stored it.  Therefore, it is likely that your loop that reads the values *never* needs to access RAM.

Comment: I don't see how your answer pertains to the question. Irrespective of how much cache is faster than RAM, and how much prefetching the cache system does (because of the linear and sequential access pattern,) still all the data are actually being pulled in from RAM to cache. This, in my opinion, constitutes "*reading*", which means that in fact he *can* conclude what he is concluding. (This is of course if we assume that the compiler is not eliminating OP's code.)

Comment: @yzt No. The program is writing the values before reading them, and memory write operations also cause blocks to get pulled into the cache. So it is likely that the data he is reading is already in the cache from when he initially stored it; and his loop that reads the values probably *never* needs to access RAM.

Comment: Well, that is a good point. At the time I wrote my comment, that wasn't part of your answer. I'd leave the comment there for "historical" reasons. And thanks for the clarification.

Comment: But still, since the memory block he is writing to (I'm assuming the writes you are referring to are the first few loops in which he initializes the arrays, etc.) is 25MB in size (plus a few other scattered blocks of memory) unless he has a *very* high-end CPU, the area he is writing will not fit in the CPU cache and the subsequent reads will have to go to memory (except for possibly some random remnant cache lines.) My point that while what you are describing is a real cache effect that one needs to be aware of, I don't think it has much (any) effect in this particular case.

Answer (score 2):

Cache usage is independent from program's complexity. Whenever data is read from RAM it goes into cache. Since cache has a certain size, there's always that amount of data available. If you access a memory location next to the previous, there is a good chance it will be cached already. In such case RAM is not accessed.

I would suggest reading [CPU cache wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache) to broaden your knowledge.

BTW: `val = locs[*(idx + i)][*(idx + ++i)];` are you certain that this is evaluated from left to right? I am not. This is an undefined behavior. I'd suggest putting the `++i` below the accessor line.

**//EDIT:**

**There is nothing done with the value read from memory**. It is quite possible that these instructions are not executed at all! Check the bytecode or add a `(void) val;` instruction which should force it to be generated.

Comment: @jrok AFAIK it is defined on some compilers; but in general you are right, hence my warning.

Answer (score 2):

Portions (*blocks*) of memory will be stored in the processor cache at a time, which allows the processor to quickly access those items. However, that speed is perfectly reasonable for modern memory. [Even the slowest DDR3 ram can transfer data at about 6 GB/s.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR3_SDRAM#Modules)